# What is differance between the UIAlertView's from IOS 5 to IOS 6. In My IOS 6 all server side validation messages are not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What is differance between the UIAlertView's from IOS 5 to IOS 6. In My IOS 6 all server side validation messages are not working..if We click on the Alert Button App is crash. I need Help On this.

(lldb) bt:(after bt got this log)

```
 * thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x0294209b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x80000008)
        frame #0: 0x0294209b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15
        frame #1: 0x01fc9020 UIKit`-[UIAlertView(Private) _buttonClicked:] + 294
        frame #2: 0x02944705 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
        frame #3: 0x01bd9920 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
        frame #4: 0x01bd98b8 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
        frame #5: 0x01c9a671 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
        frame #6: 0x01c9abcf UIKit`-[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
        frame #7: 0x01c99d38 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
        frame #8: 0x01c0933f UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
        frame #9: 0x01c09552 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
        frame #10: 0x01be73aa UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
        frame #11: 0x01bd8cf8 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
        frame #12: 0x035fedf9 GraphicsServices`_PurpleEventCallback + 339
        frame #13: 0x035fead0 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 46
        frame #14: 0x02e89bf5 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
        frame #15: 0x02e89962 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
        frame #16: 0x02ebabb6 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2118
        frame #17: 0x02eb9f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
        frame #18: 0x02eb9e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        frame #19: 0x035fd7e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
        frame #20: 0x035fd668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
        frame #21: 0x01bd665c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
        frame #22: 0x0000255d mobiletummy`main + 125 at main.m:14
        frame #23: 0x00002495 mobiletummy`start + 53
```

Comment: can you please add the source code here.

Comment: Do both OS versions run the same binary or did you re-compile with the iOS 6 SDK?

Comment: in previous version all validations working fine. after updating the Xcode 4.5(ios6) alerts are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Have got the same problem. Throwing UIAlert on main thread resolved the thing for me. But on ur log stack it seems that you are already one the main thread.

Comment: in previous version all validations working fine. after updating the Xcode 4.5(ios6) alerts are not working.

Comment: Really check on throwing the alert on the main thread. IOS6 really doesn't like this where IOS5 doesn't care. ([self performSelectorOnMainThread...]). To my view this is not a compilation problem, but the change they made on UIKit. If your problem persist show us the code.